# install glfw library in OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I want to learn openGL, I'm on windows7 and I'm following [this](http://www.41post.com/5178/programming/opengl-configuring-glfw-and-glew-in-visual-cplusplus-express) guide.
I have a problem with glfw library, when I download the glfw folder I can't see any folder called "lib-msvc" so I don't know what insert in this window: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are folders like lib-vc2010, lib-vc2012 and lib-vc2013 and you should select one of those depending on your Visual Studio version.

Comment: If I go to http://www.glfw.org/download.html and I click on Source package it download a zip file, I unzip it but I don't see those folders. Am I downloading the right thing?

Comment: I downloaded the binary package. I guess that if you downloaded the source package, you have to build the library yourself.